# Is there a problem with Windows 7 64-bit stopping service?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, services

I have found on Windows 7 64-bit machines that sometimes a service is unable to stop within a reasonable amount of time. This is causing issues with a client-server application when trying to uninstall or upgrade to a new version.

This does not happen all the time, but it does happen quite frequently. We believe it's not our code holding onto something because this problem does not happen on any other OS (Win7 32-bit, Vista 32-bit, XP, Vista 64-bit, etc ...).

Has anyone else seen this issue? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed it any more often than I have on Win 7 32-bit, XP, 2003, 2008, or 2008 R2.

One workaround is to set the service to "disabled," then reboot the computer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a good workaround because after we uninstall (stop server during uninstall) we then install the new version and reboot the machine. So doing two consecutive reboots is a bad user experience.